# ROS-Indigo installation on Raspberry-Pi failes on "rosmake" package

Tags: catkin, ros-comm, rosmake, raspberrypi, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS community,

I'm installing ROS on a Raspberry-Pi 2, I've followed [this guide](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi) closely to install ROS on **Jessie**.

On Section 3.3 - "Building the catkin workspace":
Running the first command - "Invoke catkin_make_isolated":

> sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo

The building process begins installing the packages (48 of them), but on package 21 - which is the **'rosmake'** package, it fails, providing the following error message:

> ==> Processing catkin package: 'rosmake'
> ==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh'
> Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
> ==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rosmake'
> make: *** No rule to make target 'cmake_check_build_system'.  Stop.
> <== Failed to process package 'rosmake':
> Command '['/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh', 'make', 'cmake_check_build_system']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rosmake && /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh make cmake_check_build_system

> 

Command failed, exiting.

I've tried building with the -j2 option, just in case, although most likely it's not related to my problem.

What can I do about it ? There don't seem to be any records of this problem on any forums etc., from what I've seen through a quick search..

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and feedback.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246503/ros-indigo-installation-on-raspberry-pi-failes-on-%22rosmake%22-package/) by [bogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28347/bogo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fgastald](https://answers.ros.org/users/28939/fgastald/) on 2017-01-03**:
same problem here but with ROSPACK..... any help will be appreciate

**Comment by [Toasted_Tiger](https://answers.ros.org/users/31718/toasted_tiger/) on 2017-08-27**:
Did you ever find the solution because I am currently struggling with Rospack aswell

**Comment by [bogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28347/bogo/) on 2017-08-30**:
@Toasted_Tiger Unfortunately no. Eventually I didn't use ROS at all for what I was doing, so had no need to fix the problem.. However, William's suggestion seems worth trying, although IIRC it fixed my specific issue but the installation got stuck on a later stage... Good luck !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your generated Makefile is messed up. Use `--force-cmake` or remove the build folder for the package that's not building (in this case `build_isolated/rosmake`) and try again.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2017-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0